# Rotation of a large image is slow in imagick

Tags: php, image-processing, rotation, imagick

I have an image size - 2756 x 1034 and trying to rotate it with php imagick. It works 70% of the times and takes around 55-65 seconds to do it, but sometimes it fails giving a 500-Internal server error.
Any Ideas how to fix it?

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
$image_file = new \Imagick("image.jpg");
$image_file->setImageFormat('jpg');
$image_file->rotateimage('#000000', 45); //rotation angle
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $image_file;
?>
```

Also I've tried to rotate it with imagick distortion but that doesn't seem to work either.
(I'm on a shared linux hosting).

Comment: You aren't rotating at right angles, so this will take a little longer to process, and I don't think there's much you can do about it. Shared hosts give you limited server resources. Sorry amigo

Comment: Thanks  delboy1978uk, so will become faster if I take a dedicated hosting?
 Are there any other options too instead of imagick which can work faster?

Comment: I can't believe that. With a well optimized function, I would expect 55-65 MILLIseconds, even with bilinar interpolation.

Comment: You can try https://imagekit.io